# How to keep a smooth UX with multiple inputs

Tags: forms, gui-design, input-fields

I'm building an app that will compare many items and offer the user only one perfect item and a bunch of interesting ones. Those are selected via a special algorithm.

The user will need to fill multiple inputs before getting the results, there will be around 7 to 10 inputs of different types (text, checkbox, drop down...). I want to offer a nice way to make the user fill all the needed info without making him bored or frustrated.

**Things I've thought of:**

- Showing 3 inputs at a time with a continue button and a nice transition between each step.
- Giving default values for those inputs, so the user can leave the default value.

Are those ideas effective? What else can I add to enhance the UX and keep it interactive?

Comment: It's difficult to provide an accurate answer without first knowing the type of data (input) you wish to extract from the user. Phycology is a major factor in Information Architecture. For example, if I'm on a site looking for apples, and I happen to see a non-intrusive radio button asking if I prefer Red apples or Green Apples, then I would be inclined to select Green apples. If that field disappears and another non-intrusive apple-based input takes its place, I would select that as well. The moment the inputs deviate from my goal of finding apples, or requests an email address, I'm done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion. The card layout suggested by @Rob would be not feasible because card layout or widget have different prospect so here it doesn't fit.

I think your scenario is not that much complicated so just go for simple and straight approach.

As you said that only 7-10 criteria would be there based on which you select the best match result. So usually mobile screen can cover 7-8 criteria easily so I think simple and mostly used list layout would be feasible because if you redirect a user to multiple screens to select the criteria then they would get irritated and bored. As per user experience, we should try to minimise the interaction so it won't be good to keep more than one screen so here below I attached example layout with different controls so that you will have a clear idea. As per my suggestion, I covered 8 points and for remaining 2 points you can keep page scrollable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make it more interactive such as a wizard, i think this is the best way to make the user more excited to fill the form.

U can go to this link and click "get a card" you will get an interactive wizard there

[Wizard Example](https://www.bankbazaar.com/credit-card.html)

> A wizard might turn out to be just such a solution if we take the
>   instinctive path, feeling that rich interactions are better than dull,
>   old menus and form fields. The Internet puts rich, entertaining media
>   at our users’ fingertips. Users don’t need our applications to
>   entertain them. So give careful consideration to whether a wizard
>   would truly support your company’s business model and your users’
>   needs or a not-so-exciting solution using menus and forms might be the
>   better one all around.

[Source](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2011/09/wizards-versus-forms.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think a form with 7-10 field section is not so long.

You should group related information in blocks to help users process the information that they must fill in, but I think is no need for steps in a form with 10 fields.

Regarding having default values, I think you should avoid this option unless you believe a really large number of users will select those values.